# Laravel webpack vue code splitting lazy routes are not versioned

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, routes, code-splitting

I'm working on a Laravel + Vue SPA project and I tried to optimize the project with code splitting and defining lazy routes, but now every lazy route file are not being versioned.

Let's see if I can describe the problem.

[image]

You can see here the main files are versioned: `app.css`, `app.js`, `vendors.js`.
But what happens with `users.js`? It's a lazy route.

`app.blade.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ca_ES">
<head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/fullscreen-manifest.json">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.png') }}">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ mix('vendors.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`routes.js`

```
const home = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/pages/home');
const login = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/pages/auth/login');
const pageNotFound = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/pages/errors/404');
const pageForbidden = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ '@/pages/errors/403');

import users from "./users";
import profile from "./profile";
(...)

export default [
    ...users,
    ...profile,
    (...)
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: home,
        meta: {
            auth: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/forbidden',
        name: '403',
        component: pageForbidden,
        meta: {
            auth: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: login,
        meta: {
            guest: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        name: '404',
        component: pageNotFound,
    }
];
```

`users.js`

```
const users = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "users" */ '@/pages/users/index');
const show = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "users" */ '@/pages/users/show');

export default [
    {
        path: '/users',
        name: 'users',
        component: users,
        meta: {
            auth: true,
            admin: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/show/:id',
        name: 'users.show',
        component: show,
        meta: {
            auth: true,
            admin: true,
        }
    },
];
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = {
    output: {
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.join(__dirname, './resources/js'),
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            analyzerMode: 'static',
            openAnalyzer: false,
            reportFilename: 'bundle-analyzer-plugin/reports/' + moment().format('YYYYMMDD') + '.html'
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: '[path].gz[query]',
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.7
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```
const config = require('./webpack.config');
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/pdf.scss', 'public/css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}

mix.webpackConfig(config);
```

So what am I doing wrong? I can import all lazy routes files on the app.blade.php and it would be importing with versioning, but I will be missing the point... The idea is this files are being include when the websites need them. But when they do that automatically it does without versioning.

Comment: can you put your `route.js` or router file

Comment: Updated, you can see I'm using a lot of files for better structure.

Comment: Have you tried appending your version to `chunkFilename` like `chunkFilename: '[name].js?t=' + new Date().getTime()`?

Comment: Then the problem is on `app.blade.php` I cannot import vendors.js. `Unable to locate Mix file: /vendors.js. (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/app.blade.php)`. And I think it's unappropiated adding the time suffix on importing the file.

Answer (score 0):

as you are using `Vue Router` so you should use `Dynamic Imports` like this

```php
export default [
    {
        path: '/users',
        name: 'users',
        component: () => import('@/pages/users/index'),
        meta: {
            auth: true,
            admin: true,
        }
    },
    {
        path: '/show/:id',
        name: 'users.show',
        component: import('@/pages/users/show'),
        meta: {
            auth: true,
            admin: true,
        }
    },
];
```

ref link https://laravel-news.com/using-dynamic-imports-with-laravel-mix

Comment: You wrote both routes different. I understand the first is the correct. But this is exactly what I'm doing... watch the first lines on users.js. `const users = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "users" */ '@/pages/users/index');`

Comment: in vue router don't use `const` inside component you can use `const` dynamic import  for more details read that ref link